# R dies unexpectedly with segmentation fault when loading 'xlsx' and 'caret' in that order

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, r-caret, r-xlsx

When I load `xlsx` followed by `caret`, `R` dies with `segmentation fault`.

```
> library("xlsx")
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, if I load `caret`first, followed by `xlsx`, R works fine.

```
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
> library("xlsx")
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
>
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

UPDATE:

```
OS: CentOS 6.9
R:  3.2.5
R configured with: 
./configure --enable-R-shlib CFLAGS=-fPIC --with-cairo --with-libpng --with-jpeglib --with-libtiff --with-system-zlib --with-system-pcre --with-system-xz --with-tcltk
```

`devtools.SessionInfo` output

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8          LC_NUMERIC=C                
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8          LC_NAME=en_US.utf8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_US.utf8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.utf8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.utf8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] randomForest_4.6-12 class_7.3-14        xlsx_0.5.7         
 [4] xlsxjars_0.6.1      rJava_0.9-8         MASS_7.3-47        
 [7] TTR_0.23-1          caret_6.0-76        ggplot2_2.2.0      
[10] lattice_0.20-34     devtools_1.13.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8        nloptr_1.0.4       plyr_1.8.4             iterators_1.0.8   
 [5] tools_3.2.5        xts_0.10-0         digest_0.6.10      lme4_1.1-12       
 [9] memoise_1.0.0      tibble_1.2         nlme_3.1-128       gtable_0.2.0      
[13] mgcv_1.8-16        Matrix_1.2-7.1     foreach_1.4.3      parallel_3.2.5    
[17] SparseM_1.74       withr_1.0.2        stringr_1.1.0      MatrixModels_0.4-1
[21] stats4_3.2.5       grid_3.2.5         nnet_7.3-12        minqa_1.2.4       
[25] reshape2_1.4.2     car_2.1-3          magrittr_1.5       scales_0.4.1      
[29] codetools_0.2-15   ModelMetrics_1.1.0 splines_3.2.5      assertthat_0.1    
[33] pbkrtest_0.4-6     colorspace_1.3-1   quantreg_5.29      stringi_1.1.2     
[37] lazyeval_0.2.0     munsell_0.4.3      zoo_1.7-13
```

Comment: @Eric Interesting comment. I have four questions. 1. Could you give more details on how xlsx poisons the configuration to prevent caret from loading? For example, which parameter(s) it will change to lead to the problem of loading caret. 2. Is there a solution to this type of problem, or it cannot be fixed due to some intrinsic flaw inside the design of R? 3. If it can be fixed, do the developers in the R community know about the problem? Do they have any plan to fix it? If R is bad, then which language you'd suggest to replace R? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this, I was able to fix it using the dev version of XLSX. For me it was an issue after updating to 10.13.5

```r
devtools::install_github('dragua/xlsx', ref='7ed97ff')
```

That library works for me. Strange that I have the issue *now*, a full 11 months after many others reported an issue with Ubuntu.